# Using NEST, Index documents in ElasticSearch which is authenticated using Jetty

Tags: elasticsearch, jetty, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I have authenticated a machine which hosts Elastic Search, using Jetty plugin. Everything works fine with respect to security. But my problem is I need to add documents / update documents in the same index which is secured using Jetty. In NEST I tried to find anything related to a method connecting uri(secured by jetty) with username and password to index my data. But no method or API helps out.

I need to know "Whether NEST supports, indexing Elastic Search secured by Jetty" and if answer is yes, then please tell how it can be done.

Thanks,
PDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try putting the username/password in the URI that you are using to connect to your Jetty secured Elasticsearch index.

```
 http://username:password@elasticsearchhost:9200
```

Since you are required to pass a `Uri` object to the `ConnectionSettings` for NEST you can set it like the following:
(*Updated 4/25/14 -  reflect correct usage with `Uri` class.*)

```
 var uri = new Uri("http://username:password@elasticsearchhost");
 var client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(uri));
```

Comment: Second code snippet won't work as UserInfo is read-only according to documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.userinfo 
First snippet works great.